# Are those movie masks for real where A impersonates B?

Tags: realism, make-up

You know the kind I mean. At the intro of Mission Impossible, we see Tom Cruise, who suddenly hooks a hand beneath his jaw and tears of his face, which turns out to be one of those vinyl masks. Beneathe the mask, he's somebody totally different.

I have seen Mrs Doubsfire, where Robin williams wears one of thsoe masks and can seriously pass for an old lady, and even still has facial mobility. So I suppose it can be done, to a degree.

Given that the guy wearing the mask has a small face, small nose etc, could he really pass convincingly for someone else if he wore a mask?

Comment: Mythbusters [took it on once](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUKy3483eA8), showing that (at least 3 years ago) the technology isn't quite there yet. It could fool some people from far away, though, and a dog up close.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Think of the cost savings if you could have an unknown extra simply wear a Tom Cruise mask for the role.

Answer (score 0):

No they aren't real and they are, the usual process of creating this affect is to use the actual actors for their specific roles Just like they do on Face/Off and then using a quick cut when they go to remove the mask they will apply a decent Mask then so they have something to rip off.

Comment: Wait.   So that wasn't Nicolas Cage in a John Travolta mask and John Travolta in a Nicolas Cage mask?